# How to use the barcode captured with a scanner using DataWedge?

Tags: android, datawedge

How does DataWedge works? I read that you have to create a profile from the app and associate it with your app, but after that, in my app, how can I use the barcode I have just scanned? For like displaying it in a textview or send it to a server.
I can't find anything on the documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The profile defines how the barcode will be delivered to your application.

A typical choice is to use `Intent`s, for example a broadcast intent with a specific action. Your application can then set a `BroadcastReceiver` up. The read barcode will be available in the intent as the `com.symbol.datawedge.data_string` extra.

An [tutorial](https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/8-0/guide/samples/tutorial-ReceiveScannedData/) using broadcasted intents.

The content of the received intent is detailed [here](https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/8-0/guide/output/intent/)

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thank you. Could you please refer me to some documentation where is written how to build the app in that tutorial?